# Newton Raphson Method for double roots

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I am currently working on Newton Raphson Method.

I am kind of facing a problem how Newton Raphson Method work on more than second order quadratic functions with double roots. I have googled and found some information on it. The information says that Newton Raphson Method is slow on double roots,

Why? 
How do I know if the function has double roots?

Please let me have your advice.
I am sorry if I have placed my question in the wrong places.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The usual method is slow for double roots because of the following Taylor series argument. Assume $f$ is twice continuously differentiable and $r$ is a single root, i.e. $f(r)=0$ and $f'(r) \neq 0$. Then

\begin{eqnarray*}\left ( x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \right ) - r & = & x - r - \left ( x - r + \frac{f''(r)}{2 f'(r)} (x-r)^2 + o((x-r)^2) \right ) \\
& = & \frac{f''(r)}{2 f'(r)} (x-r)^2 + o((x-r)^2)
\end{eqnarray*}

What I did here was Taylor expand $\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ to second order about $x=r$, and then substitute in the fact that $f(r)=0$, which cancels a lot of terms. The result means that when $r$ is a single root, the method converges quadratically. Roughly speaking this means that the number of correct digits double at each step, once the error is small enough. On the other hand, if it is a double root (i.e. $f(r)=f'(r)=0$ and $f''(r) \neq 0$), we have a different situation. Here we cannot expand $f(x)/f'(x)$ about $x=r$ because this function is not defined there. Instead we must do the following:

\begin{eqnarray*}\left ( x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x)} \right ) - r & = & x-r - \frac{1/2 f''(r) (x-r)^2 + o((x-r)^2)}{f''(r)(x-r) + o(x-r)} \\
& = & x-r -\frac{1/2 (x-r) + o(x-r)}{1 + o(1)} \\
& = & x-r - (1/2 (x-r) + o(x-r))(1+o(1)) \\
& = & 1/2 (x-r) + o(x-r)
\end{eqnarray*}

This means the method converges linearly with a coefficient of $1/2$. This means the error is approximately halved at each step, once the error is small enough, which basically means that you gain a correct binary digit at each step. This gets even worse for higher order roots: for a root of order $n$ we have a coefficient of $1-\frac{1}{n}$.

There is a modified Newton method which can detect proximity to a non-simple root and modify $f$ in such a way that quadratic convergence is recovered. If you know the order of the root is $n$, then you can use

$$x_{k+1} = x_k - n \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}.$$

A similar argument to the first one shows that this converges quadratically. If you don't know the order of the root, there is a method which can estimate it: see http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/n2003/NewtonAccelerateMod.html

Edit: the symbol $o(f(x))$, called "little oh notation", is a standard shorthand. It means an unspecified function $g(x)$ such that $g(x)/f(x) \to 0$ as $x$ tends to something specified by context (usually $0$ or $\infty$, in this case $0$). So for example, calculus tells us that

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x) - h f'(x)}{h} = 0$$

which is the same as

$$f(x+h) - f(x) - h f'(x) = o(h)$$

Little oh notation has a weaker counterpart, called "Big oh notation". That is, the symbol $O(f(x))$ means an unspecified function $g(x)$ such that $g(x)/f(x)$ is *bounded* as $x$ tends to something specified by context.

Comment: Thank you for your time work. However, I don't really follow what you are saying. I really want to understand this topic, but it looks like there is no way I can understand it. I am not really deep in maths.

Comment: Other than the $o$ notation, which is really just a convenient shorthand, everything I'm describing is covered in two semesters of calculus. I can explain what $o$ means if you want.

Comment: Please do so, I want to understand it. And please tell me if I need to understand Tayler series.

Comment: You do need to understand Taylor series or at least second order Taylor approximations in order to understand the convergence properties of Newton's method.

Comment: I will study Taylor series and can I have a reason why I need to know Taylor series before I get to know it?

Comment: With Newton's method, you want to show that $f(x)/f'(x)$ is close to $x-r$ if $x$ is close enough to $r$. Basic differential calculus tells us that $f(x) \approx f'(r) (x-r)$ (since $f(r)=0$) and $f'(x) \approx f'(r)$, so $f(x)/f'(x) \approx x-r$. Taylor series are how you estimate the error in these approximations.

Comment: Thank you and I will dig into Taylor series and will come back to it.

Comment: @Ian In the 2nd equation, why it is $o((x-r)^2)$ and not $o((x-r)^3)$ in the numerator of the fraction? Similarly, for the denominator, I think it should be $o((x-r)^2)$.

Comment: @uuuuuuuuuu Technically, if you assume $f$ is only twice continuously differentiable, then the error on the second order Taylor expansion is just $o((x-r)^2)$, and the error in the first order Taylor expansion of $f'$ is only $o(x-r)$. If you assume $f$ is three times continuously differentiable then you can improve those to $O((x-r)^3)$ and $O((x-r)^2)$ respectively.

Comment: @Ian I have another question. Why the error is halved every time? We have an extra $o(x-r)$ term i.e., $c(x-r)$ where $c$ can be anything. Then, $\frac{1}{2}+c$ would be the "convergence rate", right?

Comment: @uuuuuuuuuu No, the second term is asymptotically smaller than the first one, i.e. if you divide it by $x-r$ then it goes to $0$ as $x \to r$ whereas the first one goes to $1/2$. So the error isn't *exactly* halved for sure but it is "basically" halved once it is small enough.

Answer (score 2):

The usual fast convergence of Newton-Raphson depends on the function having a nonzero derivative at the root.

If there's a multiple root, then the derivative at the root is 0 and this doesn't hold anymore. In the *best* case the root is a double root, and the function looks locally like a parabola touching the $x$-axis near the root. Then the error is *halved* for each iteration of the approximation, rather than *squared*, and the number of iterations you need is proportional to the number of correct digits you want to find. (For single roots, the number of iterations is proportional to the *logarithm* of the number of correct digits desired).

Comment: I am kind of understanding what you are saying, literally. Can you please make it a little simpler for me to understand. I don't think I am deep in mathematics.